# Conditional sum of a variable (based on a date range), by unique participant IDs

Tags: r, date, conditional-statements, sum

I have two separate data frames, which reflect the listening activity of users of an audiobook app over the course of a certain number of weeks.

**DF 1 ("listened")** lists, in each separate row, an individual listening-instance, per individual user, on a particular date (year-month-day format). Column #1 in DF1 lists individual User-IDs ("dash_ID"). Column #3 ("date") in DF1 lists the date of a particular instance that each user listened to the app. Column #12 ("time_elapsed_min") lists the duration of each listen-session in minutes-elapsed. Because DF1 is a log of user activity over the course of a certain number of weeks, there are repeated user IDs in the first column, with each row reflecting a separate instance of that user listening to the app (either listening multiple times on the same date, or listening on different dates).

Here's **DF1** (**"listened"**) (it's a big data set, so I'm just sharing dput(head(listened)) here:

```
structure(list(dash_ID = c("smartstudy1051", "smartstudy1051", 
"smartstudy1051", "smartstudy1051", "smartstudy1051", "smartstudy1051"
), date = structure(c(19331, 19361, 19324, 19326, 19359, 19355
), class = "Date"), time_elapsed_min = c(6.57, 5.62, 3.3, 5.13, 
6.83, 6.25)), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, 
-6L))
```

**DF 2 ("dates")** lists, in each row, three important "milestone" dates of each user's app-usage (i.e., "date1", "date2", "date3"). There are no duplicate user-IDs in this second data frame, because this data frame reports an overall summary of the listening activity for each individual user. And here is **DF2 ("dates")**:

```
structure(list(dash_ID = structure(1:81, levels = c("smartstudy1008", 
"smartstudy1009", "smartstudy1010", "smartstudy1011", "smartstudy1012", 
"smartstudy1013", "smartstudy1014", "smartstudy1015", "smartstudy1016", 
"smartstudy1017", "smartstudy1018", "smartstudy1019", "smartstudy1020", 
"smartstudy1021", "smartstudy1023", "smartstudy1024", "smartstudy1025", 
"smartstudy1026", "smartstudy1027", "smartstudy1029", "smartstudy1030", 
"smartstudy1031", "smartstudy1032", "smartstudy1033", "smartstudy1034", 
"smartstudy1035", "smartstudy1038", "smartstudy1039", "smartstudy1040", 
"smartstudy1041", "smartstudy1042", "smartstudy1043", "smartstudy1044", 
"smartstudy1045", "smartstudy1046", "smartstudy1047", "smartstudy1048", 
"smartstudy1049", "smartstudy1050", "smartstudy1051", "smartstudy1052", 
"smartstudy9003", "smartstudy9004", "smartstudy9005", "smartstudy9006", 
"smartstudy9007", "smartstudy9008", "smartstudy9009", "smartstudy9010", 
"smartstudy9011", "smartstudy9012", "smartstudy9013", "smartstudy9014", 
"smartstudy9015", "smartstudy9016", "smartstudy9017", "smartstudy9018 (same person as 9022)", 
"smartstudy9019", "smartstudy9020", "smartstudy9021", "smartstudy9023", 
"smartstudy9024", "smartstudy9025", "smartstudy9026", "smartstudy9027", 
"smartstudy9028", "smartstudy9030", "smartstudy9031", "smartstudy9032", 
"smartstudy9033", "smartstudy9034", "smartstudy9035", "smartstudy9037", 
"smartstudy9038", "smartstudy9039", "smartstudy9040", "smartstudy9041", 
"smartstudy9042", "smartstudy9043", "smartstudy9044", "smartstudy9045"
), class = "factor"), Intervention.End.Date = structure(c(19134, 
19134, 19134, 19148, 19176, 19176, 19176, 19176, 19183, 19183, 
19183, 19197, 19218, 19218, 19239, 19267, 19253, 19260, 19253, 
19274, 19267, 19281, 19309, 19295, 19302, 19316, 19330, 19337, 
19330, 19337, 19344, 19351, 19351, 19351, 19351, 19358, 19358, 
19358, 19365, 19365, 19372, 19183, 19190, 19190, 19232, 19232, 
19225, 19239, 19232, 19246, 19295, 19260, 19281, 19288, 19295, 
19295, 19295, 19302, 19302, 19302, 19316, 19337, 19351, 19351, 
19358, 19365, 19372, 19372, 19386, 19386, 19386, 19400, 19400, 
19400, 19400, 19407, 19407, 19407, 19407, 19421, 19421), class = "Date"), 
    Follow.up.End.Date = structure(c(19176, 19176, 19176, 19190, 
    19218, 19218, 19218, 19218, 19225, 19225, 19225, 19239, 19260, 
    19260, 19281, 19309, 19295, 19302, 19295, 19316, 19309, 19323, 
    19351, 19337, 19344, 19358, 19372, 19379, 19372, 19379, 19386, 
    19393, 19393, 19393, 19393, 19400, 19400, 19400, 19407, 19407, 
    19414, 19225, 19232, 19232, 19274, 19274, 19267, 19281, 19274, 
    19288, 19337, 19302, 19323, 19330, 19337, 19337, 19337, 19344, 
    19344, 19344, 19358, 19379, 19393, 19393, 19400, 19407, 19414, 
    19414, 19428, 19428, 19428, 19442, 19442, 19442, 19442, 19449, 
    19449, 19449, 19449, 19463, 19463), class = "Date")), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, -81L))
```

I would like to add a new column to the **DF2** **"dates"** dataframe, which would report the sum of each user's total time spent listening to the app, between **date2** and **date3**. (So, I'm thinking this would mean a conditional sum of the minutes-elapsed listed in Column #12 of DF1 ("listened"), by unique "dash_ID", only if those minutes-elapsed occurred between **date2** and **date3** listed for the corresponding dash_ID in the "dates" dataframe -- and then I'd like to append these sums, to a new column in "dates", corresponding to each individual user). For the date range, I would like only listening-sessions that occurred **after** date2 and up to and including date3 to be counted towards the total sum of elapsed minutes.

I'm still a beginner in R and am a bit stuck on how to do this. I tried a few different approaches with base R and tapply, but I'm still stuck. I haven't been using R for very long and am having some trouble with how to write syntax that would allow me to work with the data between the two data sets. I have already converted the dates into the date class to ensure proper handling by R.

Comment: plase share the data

Comment: Hello @wangki - as a previous commenter mentioned please follow the instructions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/collectives/r-language/articles/76995406/how-to-write-a-good-r-question-with-a-reproducible-example) to provide us with easily usable data and code to help you solve your problem.

Comment: Thanks for bearing with me, everyone! I'm also new to stackoverflow!

Comment: just to clarify - Intervention.Start.Date is date 1, Intervention.End.Date is date 2, and Follow.up.End.Date is date 3 right?

Comment: Ah, sorry if that was a bit confusing. Yes, that's correct!

Comment: that's okay! one more point of clarification- when you say, *I would like only listening-sessions that occurred after date2 and up to and including date3 to be counted towards the total sum of elapsed minutes.* I assume this means for (say) one where the Intervention End Date is 2023-01-08, you want listening periods starting with those on 2023-01-09?

Comment: also, I removed a bunch of columns from your input which were seemingly not relevant to answering your question. If I'm mistaken, feel free to roll back to the previous version!

Comment: Hi Mark, yes, that's correct regarding the dates. Thanks for your time!

Comment: It sounds like a `data.table` non-equi join would work. Have you tried something like `setDT(DF2)[setDT(DF1), on = .(dash_ID, Intervention.Start.Date < date, Follow.up.End.Date >= date), total_time_elapsed := sum(time_elapsed_min)]`?

Answer (score 1):

You could do something like this:

Steps:

1. Create a follow up start date column by adding one day onto the date of the end of the intervention
2. Left join with the listened column, joining by dash_ID and then the dates in listened which are within the follow up period dates in `dates`
3. Create a total column, summing time elapsed, grouped by dash_ID and follow up start date (this second grouping might not be needed, if each patient only has one intervention, but if not then include this)

```
library(dplyr)

dates |> 
  mutate(Follow.up.Start.Date = Intervention.End.Date + 1) |>
  left_join(listened, join_by(dash_ID, between(y$date, x$Follow.up.Start.Date, x$Follow.up.End.Date))) |>
  mutate(total = sum(time_elapsed_min), .by = c(dash_ID, Follow.up.Start.Date))
```

Output:

```
# A tibble: 81 × 7
   dash_ID        Intervention.End.Date Follow.up.End.Date Follow.up.Start.Date
   <chr>          <date>                <date>             <date>              
 1 smartstudy1008 2022-05-22            2022-07-03         2022-05-23          
 2 smartstudy1009 2022-05-22            2022-07-03         2022-05-23          
 3 smartstudy1010 2022-05-22            2022-07-03         2022-05-23          
 4 smartstudy1011 2022-06-05            2022-07-17         2022-06-06          
 5 smartstudy1012 2022-07-03            2022-08-14         2022-07-04          
 6 smartstudy1013 2022-07-03            2022-08-14         2022-07-04          
 7 smartstudy1014 2022-07-03            2022-08-14         2022-07-04          
 8 smartstudy1015 2022-07-03            2022-08-14         2022-07-04          
 9 smartstudy1016 2022-07-10            2022-08-21         2022-07-11          
10 smartstudy1017 2022-07-10            2022-08-21         2022-07-11          
   date   time_elapsed_min total
   <date>            <dbl> <dbl>
 1 NA                   NA    NA
 2 NA                   NA    NA
 3 NA                   NA    NA
 4 NA                   NA    NA
 5 NA                   NA    NA
 6 NA                   NA    NA
 7 NA                   NA    NA
 8 NA                   NA    NA
 9 NA                   NA    NA
10 NA                   NA    NA
# ℹ 71 more rows
```

Note: In the output preview, you can see all of the values are NAs in the new columns. This is because the left join adds the values in listened where they match the row in dates, and if nothing matches, it adds NAs. If you want the `total` column to be `0` in these rows, you can replace `sum(time_elapsed_min)` with `sum(time_elapsed_min, na.rm = TRUE)`. If you want to remove the non-matching rows entirely, you can use an inner join. Feel free to write a comment if you have any questions or this is at all confusing!

Comment: Thank you, Mark! This works! The second grouping by intervention start isn't relevant, since there was only one group assignment per patient, so I've just omitted that from the last step.